# removing the applied styles to IText

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have a IText object added in canvas where I change the style of each word in the text dynamically , here style is updating fine , but I am not being able to clear the previous style applied . hence each time new style is overridden on previous

```
function updateStyle(){

                    clearItextStyle();
                    var letterArray =getLetterIndex(iText.getText());
                    var counter=1;
                    for(var i=0;i<selectionArr.length;i=i+2){
                            iText.setSelectionStart(selectionArr[i]);
                            iText.setSelectionEnd(selectionArr[i+1]+1);
                            switch(counter){
                                case 1:
                                iText.setSelectionStyles({"textDecoration":"underline"});
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                iText.setSelectionStyles({"textDecoration":"overline"});
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    iText.setSelectionStyles({"textDecoration":"line-through"});
                                    break;
                            }
                            counter++;
                            if(counter>3){
                                counter=0;
                            }


                    }


                    canvas.renderAll();

              }



              function clearItextStyle(){

                text.setSelectionStart(0);
                text.setSelectionEnd(iText.getText().length-1);
                text.setSelectionStyles(null);
                canvas.renderAll();

             }
```

Comment: Use text.remove(); to clear the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function clearItextStyle(){
        text.remove();
        text=addIText();  // Initialize IText object here again
        canvas.add(text);
        canvas.renderAll();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear a "textDecoration" style for an IText element, you can set that style to "none", e.g.

```
text.setSelectionStyles({"textDecoration":"none"});
```

Answer (score 0):

reset styles of an itext object:

```
itext.styles = { }; // -> space is important
canvas.renderAll();
```

Then you can add back styles.